# @JsonProperty not taking Case , as given title case its coming lowercase

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

**1 Parent DTO**

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
public class OfferResponse {

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("Status")
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("Offer")
    private List<Offer> offers = null;  // child dto Offer

    }
```

**2
 Offer DOT is child  of OfferResponse DTO**

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
public class Offer {

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("Type")
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty("Pricing")
    private List<Pricing> pricing = null;  // child dto Pricing
    @JsonProperty("Timing")
    private List<Timing> timing = null;    // child dto Timing

}
```

**3.1
 Pricing DTO is child of Offer DTO**

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
public class Pricing {

    @JsonProperty("Name")  // in a response its coming name (?? why in lowercase while already given in title case
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("Type")  // in a response its coming type (?? why in lowercase while already given in title case
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty("SKU")   //in a response its coming sku (?? why in lowercase while already given in title case
    private String sKU;

    }
```

**3.2
// schedule DTO is child of Offer DTO**

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY)
public class Schedule {

    @JsonProperty("Sample")   // in a response its coming sample (?? why in lowercase while already given in title case
    private String tier;
    @JsonProperty("Lower")

}
```

but in a response i am getting child Attribute in lowercase  while i have given in Title Case in @JsonProperty

Response:

```
  {
    "OfferResponse": {
        "Id": "1234",
        "Status": "SUCCESS",
        "Name": "Sadina",
        "Offer": [{
            "Name": "Tata Docomo",
            "Type": "PostPaid",
            "Pricing": [{
                "name": "100rs per month",
                "type": "accessory",
                "amount": "100",
                "tpu": "4321"
            }],
            "Schedule": [{
                "sample": "test for long"
            }]
        }]

    }
}
```

given above response is coming but i am looking for all attribute tags should be upper camel case

Comment: json you have provided is not a valid json.

Comment: Your problem is caused in the code that you "did not bother to include, because it is not important".  Also, consider updating to a newer version of Jackson.  you are using deprecated annotations which may indicate that you are using an old version of Jackson.  The classes you included can never compile.  Finally, as mentioned by @michalk your example JSON is 0% valid.

Comment: @michalk & DwB  kindly check now i have given proper json now

Answer (score -1):

You can use @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class). this will do to capitalise all property names in the JSON message.